# Pandas: Get datetime index value from row

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe with datetime type column set to index. 
I want to process the data per row with apply function. how can I access the index value of the current row?

```
                      hid      lat        lon  
2016-08-11 10:56:00  549  40.639504 -79.996961   
2016-08-11 10:57:00  639  40.539504 -79.993981   
2016-08-11 10:58:00  749  40.438842 -79.924733 

def f(row):
    # I want to access row idx value here

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: f(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since apply will return a Series you could call the name of that Series which represent the index such has:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.name, axis=1)
```

Comment: If you don't pass `raw=True`, apply returns a Series actually. You might be able to get the row index by `df.apply(lambda row: row.index, axis=0)` but of course your suggestion makes more sense.

Comment: @ayhan you are actually right, it returns a Series even on axis=1, so you can call the name of it, fixed the answer.

Comment: @ayhan it doesn't work to me; when i pass the datetime index with apply it is passed the entire series of all the datetime, not the value of the specific row index. Any suggestion?